# PHP array is not populated with data provided in constructor of symfony2 entity class

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

In my php class (symfony2 entity class) I have class variable avaliable:

```
protected $avaliabletags = array();
```

Than in constructor I am putting data into that array:

```
/**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->avaliabletags['zatwierdzony']['name'] = "Zatwierdzony";
        $this->avaliabletags['zatwierdzony']['role'] = "ROLE_ACCEPTTAG";
        $this->avaliabletags['zatwierdzony']['label'] = "";
        $this->avaliabletags['finalized']['name'] = "Finalized";
        $this->avaliabletags['finalized']['role'] = "ROLE_ACCEPTDOC";
        $this->avaliabletags['finalized']['label'] = "";
    }
```

However the above code does not seem to populate class variable.

Using `print_r` on `$this->avaliabletags` result in `array()`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you call `print_r`? Are you sure that between `constructor` and call for `print_r` you don't clear an array?

Comment: I have searched the class file and found no other references to $avaliabletags. Nonetheless I have doubts whether __construct() is executed as putting there die(); does not result in blank page.

Comment: Show us the code where you test array value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is connected with the constructor not being called.

According to the doctrine2 documentation Doctrine2 never calls __construct() method of entities. http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/architecture.html?highlight=construct.

Therefore I change the code into:

```
/**
 * Baza dostepnych tagów
 */
protected $avaliabletags = array(
  "zatwierdzony" => array(
    "name" => "Zatwierdzony", 
    "role" => "ROLE_ACCEPTTAG"
  ), 
  "finalized" => array(
    "name" => "Finalized", 
    "role" => "ROLE_ACCEPTDOC"
));
```